# How can I reach Amazon Linux in Hyper-V

Tags: linux, wildfly, hyper-v, amazon-linux

I hava Amazon Linux 2 running in a Hyper-V Virtual Machine, I have Wildfly running on it, so when I put

```
curl http://localhost:8080
```

[image]
It returns an html page as plain text, which is expected, now I want to reach the wildfly instance (running on 8080 port) but when I try to reach it through a browser in windows host, it refuses to connect.

[image]

is there a configuration inside Amazon Linux in order to be reachable by other browsers?

Comment: You are using the internal IP address of the machine.  This address is a [private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) that cannot be accessed from the outside world.  Your machine needs to have a public IP assigned to it.  It's not clear if it has that - we need to know the configuration of the networking.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I will try to see if it has a public ip.
I have worked with Windows Server 2019 VM with hyper-v before, I just had to put the IPv4 returned from ipconfig and voila, that's why I believe it's a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to reach wildfly21 without modifiying the following parameters in standalone.xml:

```
    <interfaces>
      <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
      </interface>
      <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
      </interface>
    </interfaces>
```

Those are the values I was looking for, 0.0.0.0 to make wildfly reachable for anyone, also you can make reachable the console too.
Amazon Linux doesn't have a Firewall or something like that, the internal IP address works fine since it's a VM.

For the ssh login this worked for me:

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config    

PasswordAuthentication yes    

service sshd restart
```